# Simple char table writing in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Hi how to write text to `char` table (`name`)?

I am trying:

```
char name[10];
char * n = name;
n = "John";
```

Why it doesnt change table: name?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `n` is a pointer that changes what it points to. The variable `name` is at a fixed location in memory. The first assignment `n = name;` sets the pointer `n` to point to `name`. The second assignment `n = "John";` sets the pointer `n` to point to the constant string `"John"`. After the second assignment, `n` no longer points to `name`.

In order to copy a string into `name` through the `n` pointer, use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(n, "John");
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Why it doesn't change table: `name`?*

Simple, because `n` points to the base address of the compile time allocated array `name`, which cannot be populated by **assignment**. To populate `name` itself, Use `strcpy()` instead.

In other words, once we write

```
 n = "John";
```

then `n` does not point to `name` anymore. It becomes a pointer to the *string literal* `"John"`. So, the content of `name` is unchanged.

> *how to write text to `char` table?*

use `strcpy()` like

```
  strcpy(n, "john");
```

or, getting rid of the pointer variable altogether, you can write

```
 strcpy(name, "john");
```

directly.

Comment: if i do something like: strcpy(name, "john"); . Is this change (name) pointer address?

Comment: @user3191398 no, this does not change the _pointer_, it changes the containt of the memory area pointed to by the pointer.